# Uniform Convergence: Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

To show that $f_k(z) = \frac{z^k}{k}$ converges uniformly for $|z| < 1 $ and that $f'_k(z)$ does not converge uniformly for $|z| < 1$, what must be done? What other things can be said about the uniform convergence of $f'_k(z)$?

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that 
$$\sup_{|z|<1} \left|\frac{z^k}{k}\right| = \frac1k$$
so $f_k$ tends uniformly to $0$.

Also $f'_k(z) = z^{k-1}$ which tend to $0$ pointwise on $|z| < 1$, but not uniformly since
$$\sup_{|z|<1} |z^k| = 1.$$

(See for yourself what will happen on slightly smaller discs: $|z| \le r$ for $r < 1$.)

Comment: @Trancot If it was helpful, you might consider upvoting the answer.